# how i can import a html file from python

Tags: python, html, flask, smtp

I want to import a html file in python for no write html in python code

I try to read the html file and the content put it in a variable but it does not read the css content

```
html = open("templates/email.html","r")
msg.add_alternative(html.read(),subtype="html")        
html.close()
```

Example:

```
import 'file.html' as html
msg.add_alternative(html,subtype="html")
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: i want to import the html file link a external file and put it where it says "html.read()"

Comment: You've tagged this as flask. If you want to add variables to your template then you've gone totally off-course and you need to follow some flask tutorials. Jinja2 is the default templating language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will open and read the file placing it into a list variable.

```
        fileName = "filepath of the html I want to read"
        htmlText = file.text.readlines(fileName)
```

If you want to find a certain element inside the htmlText variable (inside the HTML). I would suggest a for loop and a substring find method like below.

```
        for i in range(0, len(htmlText):
           line=htmlText[i]
           if (line.find('some element inside HTML') != -1):
                print("I found it")
                # some other action
```

Answer (score 0):

I have it

```
from flask import render_template
html = render_template('email.html');
msg.add_alternative(html,subtype="html")
```